# Implement using JS or Workflow Wait condition in Dynamics 365 online?

Tags: dynamics-365

I have a Membership entity which has two fields Start date and End date. If Start date <= Current date then Status Reason should change to "Membership Active" and if End date <= Current date then Status Reason should change to "Membership Inactive".
I am thinking to implement in any of the below approaches.

1. Using JS, OnLoad of the record comparing Start date with current date and changing the status value.
2. Using OOB workflow Wait condition is the another approach. (If this approach is better then should we implement using two wait conditions?)

Can anyone suggest which approach is better ? Is there any other approach better than above two?

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflow and use 1 wait condition.

Answer (score 0):

Would start and end date fields be updated by user or a process or be populated on creation of a membership record? Workflow needs a trigger to start the wait counting.
With setting up a daily cloud flow, select memberships filter by the condition you're checking and update status according would be another option.